# urllib2 giving Network is unreachable error even after setting http_proxy in bash

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy, urllib2

I am trying to test my Google App Engine (Python) app locally. I need to do some URL fetching, I tried but the following error message is displayed.

```
"urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>"
```

So I tried to check whether deployment happens at all. It also resulted in same error

And then I tried in Python shell:

```
>>>import urllib2
>>>a = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com")
>>>a.code
200
>>>a.readlines
<addinfourl at 155594924 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x9443d6c>>
```

Though the response code is 200. If I do a.readlines I wouldn't get the actual HTML. (a.readlines supposed to output html?)
Before trying above I had my http_proxy variable set in the environment. I even tried by `urllib2.install_opener(ProxyConfiguredOpener)`. And it still doesn't work.

I can't do any `urllib2` URL opens, hence I can't work with a lot of tools like Google App Engine which is using `urllib2` for deployment. Can anybody tell what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`a.code == 200` means that `urllib2.urlopen()` is successful while running in Python shell.

When running in App Engine `urllib2.urlopen()` uses `google.appengine.api.urlfetch()`.

If you run it locally it should use your local network configuration. The bug [urlfetch cannot be used behind a proxy](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=544) is fixed.

Comment: Oh Yeah. 200 is Successful, but when I do a.readlines I wouldn't get the html, but something like..
    <addinfourl at 155594924 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x9443d6c>>

Comment: add `()` To call a callable in Python.

Comment: Oops what I was doing! Sorry, but the App Engine Deployment is still giving the same network unreachable error.

Comment: @Sravan: have you tried to update the SDK to the latest version? Make sure `HTTP_PROXY` (and maybe `HTTPS_PROXY`) is defined in the deployment process.